# PHP param by ref => assign to ref = NULL

Tags: php, reference

I found a strange behavior when passing parameter by reference to an object method:

```
class Test
{
    private $value;
    public  function Set($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public  function Get(&$ref)
    {
        $ref = &$this->value; //SET REF PARAMETER TO THIS VALUE BY REF
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->Set('test');
$test->Get($value1);

var_dump($value1); //NULL INSTEAD OF 'test'!
```

edit: GetByRef(...) name was wrong for this example, renamed to: Get(...)

edit2: I forgot the real test case where I stucked:

```
$test->Get($value1);
$test->Get($value2);

$value1 = 'Another test value';
echo $value2; //SHOULD BE SAME: 'Another test value';
```

$value2 does not know if value1 created or not, so the standard $value2 = &$value1 not works here.

Comment: Where are you defining the get function? 
$test->Get($value1);

Comment: Sorry, wrong name - edited

Comment: As for your "real test case": There's no reason it should behave the way you want it to behave. Don't write code like that. PHP references are no C pointers, don't treat them like they are. Explicitly assign one thing to the other, don't rely on indirect modifications.

Comment: So when I store eg. a huge array there the only way is to create a copy for each caller?

Comment: Data is not automatically copied by passing it into functions or returning it from them. PHP is more intelligent than that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning to a reference by reference. This is why you get `null`. It works fine if you assign normally:

```
public function GetByRef(&$ref) {
    $ref = $this->value;
}
```

By declaring `&$ref` in the method signature and calling the method, a variable is created in the calling scope with a default value of `null`, which is referenced inside the method as `$ref`. By doing `$ref = &$this->value` you are basically removing that reference and are creating a new reference `$ref`. Using `=&` always creates a new reference variable; if you want to change its value instead, you have to use `=` to assign to it. So the variable which was created in the calling scope remains set at its initial value `null` and its reference to `$ref` inside the method is broken.

Comment: Thank you, its clear to me now why got a NULL value. Please check my edited question. How to create a function which always set exactly same value by ref to every caller? I try to implement a unified "value bag" feature.

Comment: See my response under the question. Maybe you want to be returning an object instead? There will only ever be one copy of an object unless it's explicitly cloned, so that would behave more like you want it to.