# PHP's assignment by reference is not working as expected

Tags: php, reference

Why the following

```
class AClass
{
    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->prop = "Hello";
    }
    public function &get ()
    {
        return $this->prop;
    }
    protected $prop;
}

function func (&$ref)
{
    $ref = &$ref->get();
}

$value = new AClass();
func($value);
var_dump( $value );
```

outputs

```
object(AClass)#2 (1) {
  ["prop":protected]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
}
```

Shouldn't the `$value` variable become a reference to `$prop` and be of type `string` instead of staying of type `AClass`?

http://ideone.com/g1hTNV

Comment: The only `&` you need is the one in the function argument

Comment: @that_guy I wrote what's needed, `$value` should become a reference to `$prop`

Comment: that_guy has it. Your code on IDEone is missing the & in the function signature.

Comment: @bwoebi I'm gonna post a question with simpified code gotta let u know in a min

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP param by ref => assign to ref = NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807620/php-param-by-ref-assign-to-ref-null)

Answer (score 2):

Consider this piece of code (It's the same as your code, just without everything else):

```
$value = new stdClass;
$ref = &$value;
$var = "Hello";
$ref = &$var; // this is where you write $ref = &$ref->get();
var_dump($value);
```

This gives *as expected* an empty object and **not** `string(5) Hello`.

#### Why?

We're in line 4 *overwriting* the reference to `$value` with a reference to `$var`.

`$ref` now holds a reference to `$var`; the value of `$value` remains **unaffected**.

#### What we're not doing

- We don't assign the value of `$var` to `$value`.
- We don't assign to `$value` a reference to `$var`.

#### Conclusion

Assigning references to a variable via another referencing variable is just not possible in PHP.

Comment: As a C++ guy this is hard to grasp. Is this behavior documented anywhere? If not, it looks more like a bug, really

Comment: As an addition: _PHP reference_ has __nothing to do__ with _C/C++ pointer_

Comment: @DesmondHume References aren't pointers. People just mostly think as pointers of them...

Comment: This code does not give `string(5) Hello` like you said, it gives an empty object.

Comment: @DesmondHume fixed, confused `$var` with `$value` when testing myself :x

Comment: @DesmondHume It has. I just rewrote your code in a much simpler self-containing case to _show_ what happens. Just wrap the function around and you get the same. I wanted to __explain__.

Answer (score 0):

bwoebi is totally right about how PHP references work. Without a dereference operator it would become impossible to know exactly what you mean when using pointers, so PHP has used another approach. This does not, however, mean that what you want is impossible, you just can't do it all inside a function:

```
class AClass
{
    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->prop = "Hello";
    }
    public function &get()
    {
        return $this->prop;
    }
    public $prop;
}

function &func($ref)
{
    return $ref->get();
}

$root = new AClass();
$value = &func( $root );
var_dump( $value );
  // string(5) "Hello"
$value = "World";
var_dump( $root->get() );
  // string(5) "World"
```

http://codepad.org/gU6pfzUO

Comment: You're quite correct, but this is just going around the problem; I think he more wanted to understand _why?_...

Comment: Looking at your edit. Are objects always passed by reference?

Comment: In PHP 4 they weren't… but now, they are. (called `by object`)

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the ampersand in your `func` function. Then it will return you the string.

```
function func (&$ref)
{
    $ref = $ref->get();
}
```

Comment: If I do it, I won't be able to change the `$prop` object variable by changing `$value`, no?

Comment: @DesmondHume Yes you can change it to something else. Just append these lines to the end of your file for example: `$value = "Hi"; var_dump($value);` and try it out.

Comment: But the the objects variable `$prop` stays "Hello", I checked it

Comment: I realize my obvious mistake now too. What are you trying to achieve with this structure anyway? Perhaps it can be fixed in a better way.

Comment: I'd like to know whether it's a bug in PHP or not

Comment: How did you check the property in the object? Can you show me that code?

Comment: After the construction, make another pointer to `$value` object with `$valuePtr2 = $value;`, assign `$value` to "Hi" after `func` is called, and then `var_dump` `$valuePtr2`

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what causes this behavior. I suspect that it has to do with that you are overwriting a reference to an object to a reference to a string.

Answer (score -1):

Just change protected into public for the sake of testing.

```
$value = new AClass();
$myValue = &$value->get();

var_dump($myValue );
var_dump($value->prop);
$value->prop = 'test';
var_dump($value->prop);
var_dump($myValue );
```

Output :

```
 string 'Hello' (length=5)
 string 'Hello' (length=5)
 string 'test' (length=4)
 string 'test' (length=4)
```

incase you think that function is necessary you can use global variable.

Comment: `$value` should eventually reference the object's variable `$prop`, which is string

Answer (score -1):

what you want can be acheived by this-

```
 <?php
class AClass
{
    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->prop = "Hello";
    }
    public function &get ()
    {
        return $this->prop;
    }
    protected $prop;
}

function func (&$ref)
{
   $ref= $ref->get();

}

$value = new AClass();
func($value);
print_r( $value );
 ?>
```

Comment: After this, `$value` is not referencing `$prop`, which is wrong

Comment: ofcoarse it wont, but i guess thats what you were asking for! you wanted to change the data type of $value from class type to string, dont you? and if its changed, then how can it reference to that class?

Comment: `$value` should eventually reference the object's variable `$prop`, which is string, not the object itself

Answer (score -1):

```
class AClass
{
    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->prop = "Hello";
    }
    public function &get ()
    {
        return $this->prop;
    }
    protected $prop;
}

function func (&$ref)
{
    $ref = $ref->get(); // You don't need the ampersand here
}

$value = new AClass();
func($value);
var_dump( $value ); // outputs: string(5) "Hello"
```

Comment: How do I make `$value` a reference to `$prop` then?

Comment: Just like what you did. Modifying its value is another matter.

Answer (score -2):

Your function func() needs to return a value and then it needs to assign to a variable what func() returned. See modified code below:

```
function func (&$ref) {
    $ref = &$ref->get();
    return $ref;
}

$value = new AClass();
$new_value = func($value);
var_dump( $new_value );
```